# Display correct value when searching table with multiple rows

Tags: javascript, search, html-table

Currently I'm using this bit of Javascript to search an HTML table for matching data in a certain cell.

```
function searchTable(inputVal) {
    var table = $('#tblData');
    table.find('tr').each(function(index, row) {
        var allCells = $(row).find('td');
        if(allCells.length > 0) {
            var found = false;
            allCells.each(function(index, td) {
                var regExp = new RegExp(inputVal, 'i');
                if(regExp.test($(td).text())) {
                    found = true;
                    return false;
                }
            });
            if(found == true){
                $(row).show("highlight");
            }
            else {
                $(row).hide("highlight");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The table is setup in the following structure:

```
<tr>
<td>value1</td>
<td>value2</td>
</tr>
```

So, when searching for value1, the entire row displays - including value2.

I can't figure out how to get value2 to not display. I was trying to assign a different id for each  and then using javascript to display:none, but there are a lot of different rows and it seems like a lot of manual work for something obvious that I might be missing.

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**: Additionally, if anyone is up for it - I'm also trying to figure out how to ignore punctuation when someone searches for a value as well. Right now if the value is "that's" and someone searches "thats", it won't find a match.

Comment: You should be calling `show` and `hide` on the TD in the inner loop. And don't return `false` when you find a match, because that terminates the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This updated code will only show columns that are "found."  I think you might want to be adding css classes instead of showing and hiding.  The commented text shows how to add and remove the "highlight" class.

```
function searchTable(inputVal) {
    var table = $('#tblData');
    table.find('tr').each(function (index, row) {
        var allCells = $(row).find('td');
        if (allCells.length > 0) {
            var found = false;
            allCells.each(function (index, td) {
                var regExp = new RegExp(inputVal, 'i');
                if (regExp.test($(td).text())) {
                    $(this).show();
                    //$(this).addClass('highlight');
                } else {
                    $(this).hide();
                    //$(this).removeClass('highlight');
                }
            });

        }
    });
}
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QH5NX/)

I don't know if you have future purpose for looping through the rows, but your code can be simplified to this:

```
function searchTable(inputVal) {
    $('#tblData tr td').each(function (index, td) {
        var regExp = new RegExp(inputVal, 'i');
        if (regExp.test($(td).text())) {
            //$(this).show();
            $(this).addClass('highlight');
        } else {
            //$(this).hide();
            $(this).removeClass('highlight');
        }
    });
}
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QH5NX/2/)

Comment: This is awesome - thank you very much! Do you also know how to ignore case and punctuation for search inputs?

Comment: you can remove punctuation with `string.replace(/[^\w\d\s]/g, '');` So you can new `regExp = RegExp(inputVal.replace(/[^\w\d\s]/g, '')` and `$(td).text().replace(/[^\w\d\s]/g, '')`.